# Name for domain service

Tags: domain-driven-design

Imaging you have a domain model named "**Service**". In this case you will have domain service with name "**ServiceService**" and it's a confusing name.

Is any alternative for name "Service"?

Comment: The name `service` for the context is most likely not descriptive enough by it's own in the first place.

Comment: The domain model is supposed to reflect (model) the actual domain. Is "Service" the term described in the ubiquitous language used by domain experts and developers? If so, you should likely elaborate on a more specific term.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to add "Service" to it's name? And why do you name it only with "Service"? From naming one should find out what is the (single) responsibility of that domain service. For example, you could have a `GoodServicePayingCustomerFilter` or `InvoiceForServiceGenerator`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary domain service name to contained word "service". name what is purpose of this service provider, it is object that provides some service for its clients. domain service (service provider) examples of your domain may be ServiceNameTranslation (ServiceNameTranslation.Tranlate()) or ServiceUserNotifier (ServiceUserNotifier.Notify()),
which has service provider`s name corresponding Behavior(method,action).